# Calendar - Adding relationship to contextual date filter

Tags: views, datetime

I would like to create an Calendar view of some interships for a certain student. But when I change the Contextual (Date) filter to use an relationship no results are shown in the calendar.
When I construct a similar view page in a list instead of an calendar view mode, with identical filters, the results get returned.

Below an image of my attempt to get the relationship in a contextual date filter.
[image]
[image]

Comment: i'm pretty sure you have to add a date field to the fields and then select it in the calendar settings.

Answer (score 0):

As J. Reynolds suggested some settings in the Calender Entities must be set. Changing the relationship fixed my problem.
[image]